# Grabbing latest Twitter results

Tags: php, json, twitter

Hi I made a simple script that inserts the most recent id of a twitter post into a textfile, which then compares it too the last 100 tweets so it only retreieves the latest ones.

I have noticed that sometimes when i run this script it does not break the loop and just displays all of the old tweets again.

Is their a better approach to such a problem?

```
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);


$json= $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23Drake&count=100");

$newcount=0;    
$flag;

$id = array();
$since_filename = 'twitter/since_filename.txt';
$count_filename = 'twitter/count_filename.txt';


$since_id = file_get_contents($since_filename);

foreach($json->statuses as $tweet)
{
  $text = $tweet->text; 
  $test = $tweet->id_str;
  $id[] =  $test;


  if($test==$since_id)
  {
    break;
  }
  else
    {
        echo "false";
    }

echo $text;

  $newcount++;
}

$current = $id[0];
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($since_filename, $current);

$existingcount = file_get_contents($count_filename);
file_put_contents($count_filename, ($newcount + $existingcount));
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the Twitter API but is it suitable do post the keys here for everyone to see?

Comment: Twitter doesn't order the tweets by date order, their docs state that the results can return in any order. My best guess would be to compare each received id against the ones you already have and loop until you have a 100 unknown id's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Twitter's search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) allows you to pass a 'since_id'

> **since_id** - 
>   Returns results with an ID greater than (that is, more recent than)
>   the specified ID. There are limits to the number of Tweets which can
>   be accessed through the API. If the limit of Tweets has occured since
>   the since_id, the since_id will be forced to the oldest ID available.

```
$json= $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23Drake&since_id=$since_id&count=100");
```